# AWS Warn User About Cognito JWT Expiration / Logout Like Banks Do? AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

Cognito's automatic logout after an hour is fine for my app.  However, I would like to notify users with a dialog that notifies them that they will be logged out soon and if they want to continue instead.

I'm developing an Angular app but help in any language would be useful.

I'm not receiving a refresh token in the user object so that may complicate things.  Not sure how those work yet.

In the Cognito client settings I've selected Implicit Grant, email, openid, and aws.cognito.signin.user.admin.  Since this is for an Angular app I don't want a secret key.  However, one is included in the user response object anyway and I need to get rid of it somehow.

In the Amplify docs for Angular I found this code.  It looks useful but so far I don't have it wired up correctly and it doesn't do anything.  I'm calling it from OnInit so it gets called wihen the view is starting.  I put console.logs all through it and nothing happens.

It is called an all console.logs are posted when I intentionally log out.  Not sure I care about that because Cognito takes users to the home page which is fine.

Is this where I should start and what am I missing now?

```
import { AmplifyService }  from 'aws-amplify-angular';

public getStateChanges() {
    this.amplifyService.authStateChange$
      .subscribe(authState => {
        let signedIn = authState.state === 'signedIn';
        console.log("signedIn: ", signedIn);
        if (!authState.user) {
          this.user = null;
          console.log('Logged out!');
        } else {
          this.user = authState.user;
          this.greeting = "Hello " + this.user.username;
          console.log('greeting: ', this.greeting);
        }
     });

 }
```